# How to create new column with conditional datetime using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I am trying to add a new column containing label with this condition:

- Label 1 if delta time between value in 'time' and dt < 2 hours
- Label 0 for other case

My current idea:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./datetimecek.csv')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

dt = datetime.strptime("19/02/18 19:00", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")

datetime            time
2018/02/19 16:00    2018-02-19 16:00:00
2018/02/19 17:00    2018-02-19 17:00:00
2018/02/19 18:00    2018-02-19 18:00:00
2018/02/19 19:00    2018-02-19 19:00:00
```

And then I defined timedelta

```
a = timedelta(hours=2)

def label(c):
if dt - df['time'] < a:
    return '1'
else:
    return '0'
```

then

```
df['label'] = df.apply(label, axis=1)
```

But I got error: 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool()...

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: I think you meant to use `c` in the function definition of `label` instead of the entire `df` existing in global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want set strings `0` and `1`:

```
df['label'] = np.where(dt - df['time'] < a, '1','0')
```

Or alternative by @Dark:

```
df['label'] = (dt - df['time'] < a).astype(int).astype(str)
```

```
print (df)
           datetime                time label
0  2018/02/19 16:00 2018-02-19 16:00:00     0
1  2018/02/19 17:00 2018-02-19 17:00:00     0
2  2018/02/19 18:00 2018-02-19 18:00:00     1
3  2018/02/19 19:00 2018-02-19 19:00:00     1

print (type(df.loc[0, 'label']))
<class 'str'>
```

---

If want set integers `0` and `1`:

```
df['label'] = (dt - df['time'] < a).astype(int)
```

Alternative:

```
df['label'] = np.where(dt - df['time'] < a, 1,0)
```

```
print (df)
           datetime                time label
0  2018/02/19 16:00 2018-02-19 16:00:00     0
1  2018/02/19 17:00 2018-02-19 17:00:00     0
2  2018/02/19 18:00 2018-02-19 18:00:00     1
3  2018/02/19 19:00 2018-02-19 19:00:00     1

print (type(df.loc[0, 'label']))
<class 'numpy.int32'>
```

---

> Is there anyway I can fix this?

Yes, need change `df` to `c` for working with scalars:

```
def label(c):
    if dt - c['time'] < a:
        return '1'
    else:
        return '0'
```

Comment: I was close `np.where(dt-df['time']<a).astype(int).astype(str)` :)